# How to make a SpatialLines object from undefined - but known - spatial sequence of points in R?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I have a *SpatialPoints* object that can define a *SpatialLines* object. The problem is **I don't have any information attribute** about the sequence of the points to create the *Lines*. So, making *Lines* from points following the order of the *rows* I get lines that don't follow my desired criteria. I think I have to define some rules based on maybe:

1. **Nearest points**
2. **Direction**
3. **Or both**

How can I achieve that?

```
# Load packages
library('sp')

# Load data
x <- c(788722.0, 788764.6, 788784.1, 788774.2, 788796.7, 788755.5, 788805.7, 788745.6, 788731.0, 788815.1, 788711.8, 788708.6, 788824.9, 788699.7, 788833.6, 788690.3, 788677.9, 788842.4, 788671.9, 788665.9)
y <- c(6193202, 6193217, 6193212, 6193212, 6193197, 6193217, 6193207, 6193216, 6193202, 6193211, 6193207, 6193230, 6193217, 6193235, 6193224, 6193235, 6193236, 6193230, 6193244, 6193252)

# Define projection
epsg.32721 <- "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Create SpatialPoints object
spatialPointsObject <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialPoints
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialPoints")
box()
```

[SpatialPoints plot with order of points I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWu8M.png)[image]

```
# Create SpatialLines objects from SpatialPoints
line <- Line(coords = spatialPointsObject@coords)
lines <- Lines(slinelist = line, ID = "X")
spatialLinesObject <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(lines), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialLines + SpatialPoints
plot(spatialLinesObject, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialLines + SpatialPoints")
points(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19)
box()
```

[SpatialLines plot without the desired order of points I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rvtl.png)

[image]

## 2nd example

### Moving point 6 rightmost to exclude sort points by *x coordinate* attribute as a solution to the problem

```
# Load packages
library('sp')

# Load data
x <- c(788722, 788764, 788784, 788774, 788796, 788755, 788805, 788745, 788731, 788815, 788711, 788720, 788824, 788699, 788833, 788690, 788677, 788842, 788671, 788665)
y <- c(6193202, 6193217, 6193212, 6193212, 6193197, 6193217, 6193207, 6193216, 6193202, 6193211, 6193207, 6193230, 6193217, 6193235, 6193224, 6193235, 6193236, 6193230, 6193244, 6193252)

# Define projection
epsg.32721 <- "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Create SpatialPoints object
spatialPointsObject <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialPoints
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialPoints")
box()
```

[SpatialPoints plot with order of points I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXhP6.png)

Comment: Do you know at least which points are the ends of your line? The solution might involve constructing a graph with distance as edge weights and then finding a minimal path that visits all the nodes, which is basically the travelling salesperson problem...

Comment: @Spacedman The last point could be **point  20**. Can you share some example in R?

Comment: There's a plugin for QGIS that reconstructs lines from points using some interesting dimension reduction techniques. https://github.com/nextgis/ReconstructLine the algorithms should be portable to R if they're not available already in another package. No time for a full answer right now.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, the _ReconstructLine_ plugin in QGIS worked. But I had to select some points and then others and so on doing it interactively to avoid not desired matches. Hope I can find a solution in R.

Comment: It is possible to pull out the relevant python code from that plugin and build an R interface using the rPython package, but I think rPython is Linux/Mac only at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my own question:

**Option 1**

With a function (*MakeSpatialLineFromUnsortedSpatialPoints*) defining the *starting point* as **Point 1** of the desired line and then finding the nearest point as **Point 2**. After I got **Point 2**, finding the nearest point from **Point 2** but excluding **Point 1** to get **Point 3** and so on. To find **Point *n*** I have to find the nearest point from **Point *n-1*** excluding all the previous points from **Point *n-1***.

I also included some checks in the function to validate 1) if the input *spatialPointsObject* is a SpatialPoints class object and 2) warn if there are duplicated points.

**Option 2**

Using the *Traveling Salesperson Problem* package `TSP`.

**Input:**

```
# Load packages
library('sp')
library('rgeos')

# Define projection
epsg.32721 <- "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Load data
x <- c(788722, 788764, 788784, 788774, 788796, 788755, 788805, 788745, 788731, 788815, 788711, 788720, 788824, 788699, 788833, 788690, 788677, 788842, 788671, 788665)
y <- c(6193202, 6193217, 6193212, 6193212, 6193197, 6193217, 6193207, 6193216, 6193202, 6193211, 6193207, 6193230, 6193217, 6193235, 6193224, 6193235, 6193236, 6193230, 6193244, 6193252)

# Create SpatialPoints object
spatialPointsObject <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialPoints
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialPoints")
box()
```

**Option 1:**

```
# Function
MakeSpatialLineFromUnsortedSpatialPoints <- function(spatialPointsObject, startPointCell, projection) {

# Check if spatialPointsObject is a SpatialPoints object
  isSP = class(spatialPointsObject) == "SpatialPoints"

  if(!isSP) {

return(print("Warning: the spatialPointsObject argument is not a SpatialPoints object"))

}

# Remove duplicate points
  n = length(spatialPointsObject)
spatialPointsObject = remove.duplicates(obj = spatialPointsObject,   remove.second = TRUE)

# Warn if there are duplicate points in data
if(n > length(spatialPointsObject)) {

 print("Warning: you have duplicate points in your SpatialPoints object. The duplicated points were removed.")

}

 seqCell = integer()
 seqCell[1] = startPointCell

# Now calculate pairwise distances between points excluding previous points

for(i in 2:length(spatialPointsObject)) {

distancesFromPoint = gDistance(spgeom1 =  spatialPointsObject[seqCell[i-1]], spgeom2 = spatialPointsObject, byid=TRUE)
minDist = min(distancesFromPoint[-seqCell,])
minDistCell = as.numeric(names(which(distancesFromPoint[,][-seqCell] == minDist)))

seqCell[i] = minDistCell

}

SL = SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(slinelist = Line(spatialPointsObject[seqCell]@coords), ID = "1")), proj4string = CRS(projection))

return(SL)

}

spatialLinesObject <-   MakeSpatialLineFromUnsortedSpatialPoints(spatialPointsObject = spatialPointsObject, startPointCell = 20, projection = epsg.32721)

# Plots

# Plot SpatialPoints object
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "")

# Plot starting point
plot(spatialPointsObject[20], pch = 19, col = 'blue', add = TRUE)

# Plot SpatialLines
plot(spatialLinesObject, col = 'green', add = TRUE)
box()
```

[Plot: SpatialPoints and desired SpatialLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2388v.png)

**Update**

**Option 2:**

```
# Load packages
library('sp')
library('TSP')

# TSP
tsp <- TSP(dist(spatialPointsObject@coords))
tsp <- insert_dummy(tsp, label = "cut")
tour <- solve_TSP(tsp, method="nn", two_opt=TRUE, rep=10, start=20)
path.tsp <- unname(cut_tour(tour, "cut"))

spatialLinesObject <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(slinelist = Line(spatialPointsObject[path.tsp,]@coords), ID = "1")), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plots

# Plot SpatialPoints object
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "")

# Plot starting point
plot(spatialPointsObject[20], pch = 19, col = 'blue', add = TRUE)

# Plot SpatialLines
plot(spatialLinesObject, col = 'green', add = TRUE)
box()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
# Load packages
library('sp')

# Load data
x <- c(788722.0, 788764.6, 788784.1, 788774.2, 788796.7, 788755.5, 788805.7, 788745.6, 788731.0, 788815.1, 788711.8, 788708.6, 788824.9, 788699.7, 788833.6, 788690.3, 788677.9, 788842.4, 788671.9, 788665.9)
y <- c(6193202, 6193217, 6193212, 6193212, 6193197, 6193217, 6193207, 6193216, 6193202, 6193211, 6193207, 6193230, 6193217, 6193235, 6193224, 6193235, 6193236, 6193230, 6193244, 6193252)

# Define projection
epsg.32721 <- "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Create SpatialPoints object
spatialPointsObject <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialPoints
plot(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialPoints")
box()

# Create SpatialLines objects from SpatialPoints
tmp <- spatialPointsObject@coords
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
tmp <- tmp[order(tmp$x),]

spatialPointsObject@coords <- as.matrix(tmp)
line  <- Line(coords = spatialPointsObject@coords)
lines <- Lines(slinelist = line, ID = "X")
spatialLinesObject <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(lines), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialLines + SpatialPoints
plot(spatialLinesObject, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialLines + SpatialPoints")
points(spatialPointsObject, pch = 19)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: How can you achieve the same without using _'x'_ as the sorting variable? Because, this is a small part of a bigger dataset and sometimes some points can't be ordered using x. @Hack-R

Comment: @guzman You could sort it by something else if you preferred. I'm not sure I understand why you wouldn't be able to sort by `x` for data of any size, but I will take your word on that (however if it's something like missing value problem let me know because we can work around it). Otherwise just think of how you intuitively know where the line should be drawn, then use whatever piece of data represents that ordering to sort it. If this doesn't make sense then please provide another example illustrating what you mean so that I can answer by solving the example again.

Comment: Imagine **point 6** have bigger _x coordinate_ and it's rightmost from **point 7**. Using your methodology the line will join **point 5** with **point 7** and then **point 6**. You are right it's not a problem of sort bigger or small amount of data. it's about bigger the data, bigger the probability some points don't follow the _x sort_ rule.

Comment: @guzman Please append a 2nd example to your question showing this. I can't really understand or answer very well without the example.